# Exception while trying to use @PersistenceContext with unitName

Tags: spring, jpa, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I am using Spring 3.1, JPA 2 with Hibernate, JBoss. I want to use multiple persistence units. Here is my persistence.xml

```
    <persistence version="2.0"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
       <persistence-unit name="pu1">
          <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ds1</jta-data-source>
          <properties>
             <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/em1" />
             <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
          </properties>
       </persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="pu2">
          <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ds2</jta-data-source>
          <properties>
             <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/em2" />
             <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
          </properties>
       </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

When I am trying to create the EntityManager with the unitName like this

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="pu1")
```

I am getting exception,

```
16:56:35,834 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'languageDAOImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'pu1' is defined
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

I am doing anything wrong? If I have only one persistence unit and if I use `@PersistenceContext` without `unitName` it is working fine.

I dont know how to setup and work with multiple persistence units.

Comment: Please post the part of the spring configuration where you setup springs jpa support. I guess the problem is there.

Comment: Where is your persistence.xml located? in META-INF?